# GitHub automatically adds team to every new repository of my organization

Tags: github

I am trying to set up an automation where each time a member of my organization in GitHub creates a new repository, by default a team called "Tech Team" is added to the collaborators of this repository.

It seems this is the problem @Konrad is facing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75334147/github-automatically-adds-group-to-every-new-repository) but I want to know how to set it up.

Does anyone have a clue? It seems someone had the [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47206405/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-team-by-default-when-creating-new-repository-in-github) a while ago.